# Can't access array in React Native

Tags: react-native

```
const data = this.state.data.auctions;
const test = ()=>{
if (this.state.data == 'undefined'){
  return <Text>No Auctions</Text>
}
else{
  return <Text>{console.log(this.state.data.auctions[0].id)}</Text>
}
```

}

I am trying to render an element of an array in React Native. When I try to do this, I get the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'). This refers to me using 0 to index the array, but I cannot figure out why it is not taking it.

Comment: You have to show the entire example. We have no idea how you are setting up your state. Also you probably mean `if (this.state.data === undefined) return whatever`

Answer (score 0):

To find a solution:
try:

```
for ( i in this.state.data.auctions){
    console.log(i);
}
```

if this is null, you wont have any objects saved into this.
Or just print `this.state.data.auctions`